# OP_CHECKLOCKTIMEVERIFY . Include / reject or will not included in block?

Tags: script, input-script, checklocktimeverify

What happened if I translate to network transaction with the folowing redeem script:

```
[now + 3 months] CHECKLOCKTIMEVERIFY DROP 
DUP HASH160 [Bob's Public Key Hash] EQUALVERIFY CHECKSIG
```

1. This tx will be accepted (included in block) and after 3 month Bob can spend bitcoins?
2. Transaction will be rejected, and can only be accepted by the network when 3 month is reached?
3. Transaction will be accepted immediatly, but can be confirmed (included in block) after 3 month ?

Does it depends to input script (scriptsig)?
If yes, can you provide an example pls?
According to wiki, I just need to push some value to stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A transaction with a CLTV *output* can be created at any time, and can be accepted and confirmed immediately.

Spending such an output requires a transaction whose nLocktime field is at least the CLTV-specified time. *That* transaction will only be accepted and confirmed when its nLocktime field matches the real time.